# the choice of tenses: the present perfect/simple/continuous

Tags: tense

> 1 My boss shouts at me often. But I have put up with it.
>
> 2 My boss shouts at me often. But I put up with it.
>
> 3 My boss shouts at me often. But I am putting up with it.

Are all three correct? Which one is the most natural? What are the nuances of each?

Answer (score 1):

(2) is the most natural. (2) and (3) both describe an ongoing situation, but you might be more likely to use the continuous tense if you are adding something else, such as "I'm putting up with it for now, because I've applied for another job."

Similarly, you might use (1) with an addition. "I have put up with it until now because I'm glad to have the job after two years' unemployment."